# Recursive Synchronization vs Recursive Reentrant Lock

Tags: java, multithreading, reentrantlock

I know  thread is allowed to acquire a monitor owned by itself i.e. In Java, synchronized locks are `reentrant` as shown in example below.

My query is if i use `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock` API it will produce the same result or not, Can we have dead lock in synchronized but never in `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock`

e.g.

```
  final Object[] objects = new Object[10]

    public synchronized Object setAndReturnPrevious(int index, Object val) {
        lock.lock();//If i use this will it be same as above synchronization
        set(index, val);
        lock.unlock()//;
    }

    public synchronized void set(int index, Object val) {
        lock.lock();//
        objects[index] = val;
        lock.unlock();//
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking whether `lock` synchronizes on the same monitor as the monitor for `this` in your example? If so, the answer is no -- just as `lock2.lock()` would also not share the same monitor as `lock.lock()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Java doc ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)) and the point is very clear (emphasis mine):

> **A reentrant mutual exclusion Lock with the same basic behavior** and
>   semantics **as the implicit monitor lock accessed using synchronized**
>   methods and statements, but with extended capabilities. A
>   ReentrantLock is owned by the thread last successfully locking, but
>   not yet unlocking it. A thread invoking lock will return, successfully
>   acquiring the lock, when the lock is not owned by another thread. **The**
>   **method will return immediately if the current thread already owns** **the**
>   **lock**.

The main point is that **they both behave with the same concept**, but `ReentrantLock` lock provides additional methods to `lock()`/`unlock()`/etc.. methods which you can use them explicitly in different code blocks (methods).

Answer (score 0):

**Both synchronized and reentrant locks are same .** if you want more control and want to solve complex synchronization problems than **Reentrant Lock** is the best choice. it adds additional functionality to the implicit synchronization like ** support for Condition variables , Lock Fairness etc.** 
As a Reference Check [Java Threads 3rd Ed - Chapter 3 and Onwards](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007829.do)